# .map() over Google Map markers in React

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I'm using vanilla Google Maps in a react project and I'm hitting a wall with `.map`-ing over the markers. When I place one like this it works fine, but wrapping the marker creation in a .map function throws an error of  `Expected to return a value in arrow function  array-callback-return`.

I know I need to be returning something but since this is creating markers not returning is there a way around this? Or a different way to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

```
class App extends Component {

      state = {
        /* various states*/
        venues: []
      };

      componentDidMount(){
        this.getVenues();
        // this.renderMap();
      }

      renderMap = () => {
        /*loading gmaps script*/
        window.initMap = this.initMap

      }

      getVenues = () => {
        axios.get(`/*GET URL*/`)
              .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                  venues: response.data.results
                })
                console.log(this.state.venues);
              })
              .then(this.renderMap())
              .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
              })

    }

      // Initialize and add the map
      initMap = () => {

        var map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 12});
        })

        // Create An InfoWindow
        var infowindow = new window.google.maps.InfoWindow()
```

**Issues here**

```
       this.state.venues.map(myVenue => {

          let contentString = myVenue.name;
          console.log(contentString);

          //Create a marker
          let marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: myVenue.geometry.location.lat , lng: myVenue.geometry.location.lng},
            map: map,
            title: myVenue.name,
            key: myVenue.id
          })
          console.log(myVenue.geometry.location);
          // Click on A Marker!
          marker.addListener('click', function() {
            // Change the content
            infowindow.setContent(contentString)
            // Open An InfoWindow
            infowindow.open(map, marker)
          })

        })

      }

      render() {
        return (
          <main className="App">
           ...
          </main>
        );
      }
    }

      function loadScript(url) { ... }

    export default App;
```

Comment: You probably should return the reference for the Marker to render it after in the Map component

Answer (score 0):

[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is used to map (or change) every value of an array to a new value, usually by using the original value in some way, for example this: `[1,2,3].map(val => val + 1)` would return the array `[2,3,4]`.

In your case, where you want to loop over every element of `this.state.venues`, but not actually change any value of `this.state.venues`, I'd suggest rather using [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Just as a side note, `.map()` does not modify the original array, it returns a new one.